# How to modify the system on a live USB while running it?

Tags: fedora, drivers, live-usb

I have a live usb with Fedora 32 on it.  Before installing on a particular hardware, I'd like to add some drivers to it to make sure they work (otherwise no point in installing it to the hard disk).  Problem is, the live usb is setup so that any modifications to the system packages (e.g. `sudo dnf install git`) **do not** actually modify the usb itself, only an emulated system in memory which (obviously) gets forgotten once the system is shut down and rebooted (which is necessary after installing the drivers for them to actually load).  Hence my question:

> How can I change it so that I can add system packages to the usb drive itself (while booted from it) so that they are still there after I restart?

Answer (score 2):

The fedora Live CD or Live USB media contains it's live stuff in a squash file, which is read-only. It [use dm-snapshot or overlayfs to make it writable](https://github.com/livecd-tools/livecd-tools/), and you can install something when boot from Live CD/USB, but the modification is not persistent, as you said.

So, what you want is a feature called data persistence. And [fedora Live CD seems support data persistence feature](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD#Fedora_Live_image_features).

> 2. Data persistence options available on Live USB/SD installations.

To create a Live USB with data persistence, you need use the `livecd-iso-to-disk` tool to create the Live USB. For example:

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --overlay-size-mb 2048 Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-32-1.1.iso /dev/sdX
```

The **upperdir** of overlayfs is now on the USB instead of memory, so the modification will be persistent. For more details, follow [this document](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/index.html#using-the-livecd-iso-to-disk-tool) or see `man livecd-iso-to-disk`.

#### Note

As the document above said,

> You can perform updates just like a regular installation to your hard disk, except that kernel updates require manual intervention and overlay space may be insufficient.

So, the kernel package will not updated even with data persistence.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `livecd-creator`:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Livemedia-creator-_How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD

Which is part of the `livecd-tools` package:

```bsh
dnf install livecd-tools
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.  I do not have a system ready to go that I want to load onto a live usb.  Rather I have an existing usb and I want to *modify* the system it has on it *while running it* (just as I would modify a system booted up from my hard disk).

Comment: Fedora LiveCD does not allow that. Again you can build your own image with the packages you need.